# Как объединить несколько списков в список словарей?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, словари

Допустим, есть 3 списка:

```
names = ['A', 'B', 'C']
numbers = ['5','10','15']
colors = ['red','white','blue']
```

Как соединить эти 3 списка в словари вида:

```
{'name': A, 'number': 5, 'color': red}
{'name': B, 'number': 10, 'color': white}
{'name': C, 'number': 15, 'color': blue}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
names = ['A', 'B', 'C']
numbers = ['5','10','15']
colors = ['red','white','blue']

keys = ['name', 'number', 'color']

zipped = zip(names, numbers, colors)

dicts = [dict(zip(keys, values)) for values in zipped]
print(dicts)

# Напечатает:
# [{'name': 'A', 'color': 'red', 'number': '5'},
#  {'name': 'B', 'color': 'white', 'number': '10'},
#  {'name': 'C', 'color': 'blue', 'number': '15'}]
```

Comment: большое спасибо!

Comment: @moffire или прямо по месту: `[dict(name=name, number=number, color=color) for name, number, color in zip(names, numbers, colors)]`